# Bluetooth Speakers for Apple TV (4th Generation) Volume Control

Tags: bluetooth, appletv, airplay, sound-volume

I'm in the market for speakers for the Apple TV 4th Generation. I'd like to be able to control the volume level of the speakers via the Siri Remote. If this works via IR or Bluetooth, either option is fine.

(I'm kind of annoyed the the AppleTV does not use it's own volume control like on the iPhone when it does not have a valid audio device that it can find.)

Please, only reply if you know for sure that the speakers do work with the Siri remote once you've paired the speakers with the AppleTV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Bluetooth will do. The volume can be controlled using the Siri remote. Also, it won't have the problem of sound lagging with AirPlay. 
The only problem is that the Apple TV doesn't have a disconnect option for the Bluetooth speakers (this is a problem if you are sharing the same speakers among your computer and your Apple TV). Once you have connected with your Apple TV, there are two ways to disconnect them:

- connect the Apple TV with another Bluetooth speakers so that the first pair will disconnect.
- forget the speakers (but need to pair again next time)